# React.js: Deploy on Apache Tomcat 9 server

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I have a web app built using React.js which is quite large in size considering all of the node_modules it ended up with 700mb

However, when I run `npm run build`, the build size ends up about 20mb~

With `npm run build`, I assume that this does not include all of the node_modules since it only converts the react app into a static website

With this, is it possible to deploy a react app in Apache Tomcat container in a windows server? Without node.js? Or I need the node.js installed on my windows server for all the React libraries to work?

TIA

Comment: No, you dont need nodejs installed. You just need any http server to serve your static website. Just have to copy the build folder and  the server should serve your index.html.

Comment: Hi, @Vijay, I see but how would the libraries from node_modules work with this setup?

Comment: They would need only the browser to run JavaScript . They don't need the nodejs runtime , since it's used for UI .